# get relative path from an absolute filepath to another with Haskell

Tags: haskell, directory, filepath, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm looking for a Haskell function to give the relative path between two absolute path.
For example, giving :

1. /home/mydir/images/dir1
2. /home/mydir/docs/dir2

I would like the relative path from 1 to 2 : **../../docs/dir2**

I took a look at [filepath](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath) and [directory](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory) but I didn't find what I need.

**Is there a function or a library to do what I want ?**

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found such a function. You can build it using `filepath` utilities

```
import System.FilePath
import Control.Applicative

relativeTo :: FilePath -> FilePath -> FilePath
relativeTo path1 path2 = joinPath . getZipList $ ZipList commonPath <|> ZipList splitPath1
 where
  splitPath1 = splitDirectories . dropDrive $ path1
  splitPath2 = splitDirectories . dropDrive $ path2
  dirToDots x y = if x == y && (x /= "/")
                    then ".." 
                    else ""
  commonPath = takeWhile (/= "") $ zipWith dirToDots splitPath1 splitPath2

main = print $ "/home/mydir/docs/dir2" `relativeTo` "/home/mydir/images/dir1"
```

Behaviour with paths containing dots (e.g. `some/./path` or `some/../path`) is not tested

Comment: There is a function `makeRelative` in `System.FilePath.Posix`.